# How to solve `('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))` inside DataFlow?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm having a strange issue inside Google DataFlow, **If I run a job it works properly**, but when I run my scheduled pipeline, it throws:

```
"Operation ongoing for over 6502.03 seconds in state process-msecs in step s10 . Current Traceback:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 144, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 140, in main
    batchworker.BatchWorker(properties, sdk_pipeline_options).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 846, in run
    deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 651, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow/fipe/fipe.py", line 149, in process
  File "dataflow/fipe/fipe.py", line 41, in make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 371, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 386, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

And after some time I get the exception:

```
RuntimeError: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) [while running 'full model query car']
at send (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:498)
at send (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:643)
at request (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:530)
at request (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py:61)
at post (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py:119)
at make_request (dataflow/fipe.py:39)
at process (dataflow/fipe.py:143)
at apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (common.py:1368)
at apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (common.py:571)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1232)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (common.py:1315)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1234)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:713)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:712)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive (operations.py:215)
at apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (common.py:1395)
at apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (common.py:571)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1232)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (common.py:1299)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1234)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:713)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:712)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive (operations.py:215)
at apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (common.py:1395)
at apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (common.py:571)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1232)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (common.py:1299)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1234)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:713)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:712)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive (operations.py:215)
at apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (common.py:1395)
at apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (common.py:571)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1232)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (common.py:1299)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1234)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:713)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:712)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive (operations.py:215)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive (operations.py:212)
at apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs (common.py:1397)
at apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process (common.py:571)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1232)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (common.py:1299)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (common.py:1234)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:713)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process (operations.py:712)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive (operations.py:215)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output (operations.py:353)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:54)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:44)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:39)
at dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start (native_operations.py:38)
at execute (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py:179)
at do_work (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:651)
```

Here is my `make_request` code:

```py
def make_request(sub_path, data=None):
    retries = 0
    res = []

    while retries < 5:
        try:
            request_res = req.post(f'{BASE_URL}/{sub_path}', data=data, headers=HEADERS)
        except:
            logging.info('Erro tratado: Connection reset by peer')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            request_res = req.post(f'{BASE_URL}/{sub_path}', data=data, headers=HEADERS)

        if not request_res.ok:
            print(f'STATUS CODE {str(request_res.status_code)} - retries {retries}')
            retries += 1
        elif 'erro' in request_res.json():
            print(f'ERRO API {request_res.json()}- retries {retries}')
            retries += 1
        else:
            break

    res = request_res.json()

    return res
```

Pipeline:

```py
def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    """Main entry point; defines and runs the fipe scrapping."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    # We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
    # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    # The pipeline will be run on exiting the with block.
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        ref_date_res = make_request('/ConsultarTabelaDeReferencia')
        ref_code = ref_date_res[0]['Codigo']
        print(f'ref_code {ref_code}')

        VEHICLE_TYPES = {'car': 1, 'motorcycle': 2, 'trucks': 3}

        table_schema = 'time_created:DATE, fipe_code:STRING, autentication:STRING, fuel_type:STRING, brand:STRING, model:STRING, model_year:INTEGER, fipe_year:INTEGER, fipe_month:INTEGER, vehicle_type:STRING, value:STRING, fipe_ref_table:INTEGER'

        table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
            projectId='PROJECT',
            datasetId='DATASET',
            tableId='TABLE')

        vehicle_types_beam = (
            p
            | 'define veh types' >> beam.Create(VEHICLE_TYPES)
            | 'split veh types' >> beam.ParDo(TagData()).with_outputs(*VEHICLE_TYPES.keys()))

        veh_models = []

        for k in list(VEHICLE_TYPES.keys()):
            veh_type_models = (vehicle_types_beam[k]
                               | f'brand query {k}' >> beam.ParDo(BrandsQueryDoFn(ref_code))
                               | f'model query {k}' >> beam.ParDo(ModelsQueryDoFn())
                               | f'year model query {k}' >> beam.ParDo(ModelsYearsQueryDoFn())
                               | f'full model query {k}' >> beam.ParDo(ModelsFullQueryDoFn()))

            veh_models.append(veh_type_models)

        # (veh_models
        #  | 'merge models' >> beam.Flatten()
        #  | 'Write' >> WriteToText('bucket', file_name_suffix='.json'))

        (veh_models
         | 'merge models' >> beam.Flatten()
         #  | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('bucket', file_name_suffix='.json')
         #  | 'Load into bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
         #      table_spec,
         #      schema=table_schema,
         #      method='FILE_LOADS',
         #      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
         #      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
         #      #  custom_gcs_temp_location='bucket'
         #  )
         )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

As you can see I tried adding a `try except` and also tried to update the `requests`: `requests==2.26.0`. Any help?

Comment: What service do you use to schedule the pipeline that runs the Dataflow job?

Comment: @RiccoD What do you mean by service? I go to Pipelines inside Dataflow and created a batch data pipeline.

Comment: Are you using any virtual private clouds (VPCs)? Can you please post the pipeline options you are using (please redact any personal information)?

Comment: @Cubez I'm not using VPCs, I added the pipeline code.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto My bad. I thought what you meant with "when I run my scheduled pipeline" is that you were using Cloud Composer, Cloud Scheduler, etc. to run your job. But thanks for adding more details on your question!